# Check if iOS10 or lower during compile time

Tags: xcode, notifications, swift2, ios10

I am implementing new notifications, with UNUserNotificationCenter. But I need to keep it backwards compatible, therefore I have checks all over the place:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) { ... }
else { ... }
```

Which seems to work fine in iOS10. To be able to use the UNUserNotificationCenter framework, I have to import:

```
import NotificationCenter
```

But it crashes the iOS9.3, because it does not know what it is.
It is a compile time action, not a runtime action - so it means I can not put condition on the imports.If I create a separate class, and put

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
class ....
```

there the imports are also happening before the class implementation.
**How should I work around this issue?**

Comment: You are getting this because you imported "NotificationCenter"?

Answer (score 1):

Try navigating to Build Phases->Link Binary with Libraries and add NotificationCenter and set the status to "optional" rather than "required".

Comment: you probably meant "Build phases", I put it there and nothing changed.

Comment: meaning: I can not remove the imports from the class, it still needs it there. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you must use:

**import  UserNotifications**
for local notifications.

conditions: Xcode 8 beta 6 and Sierra beta6

some test code:

a)  iOS 10 only for swift 3:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // ADC site: 
    // Listing 1
    // Requesting authorization for user interactions
```

/*      let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter()
        center.requestAuthorizationWithOptions([.Alert, .Sound]) { (granted, error) in
        }
*/

```
    // swift 3.0:
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
    }
```

2) support iOS 9: (I have changed deployment target)

```
    // swift 3.0:

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
        }

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```